# How to upload a Google App Engine (Go) project in a different folder than the app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, go, app.yaml

My project has the following structure:

```
| appengine
|---- app.yaml
|---- myScript.go
| bower_components
|----|...
| build
|----|images
|----|----|branding
|----|----|---- favicon.ico
|----|styles
|----|----|*.css
|----|index.html
| src
| ...
```

I would like to upload the entire content of the build folder when running `goapp deploy appengine`.

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
application: myProject
version: 0-1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: ../build/\1
  upload: ../build/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

and myScript.go looks like this:

```
package myProject

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    site, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../build/index.html")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, string(site))
}
```

When I run `goapp serve appengine`, the website displays properly. However, when I try to deploy it, it only clones two files, i.e. the ones inside the appengine folder.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that, but even if you could, why complicate things unnecessarily? I mean why do this if everyone else does otherwise? Just put `app.yaml` in the root of your webapp...

Comment: Yeah, this is what I did in order to upload my website, but I really liked the idea of bundling GAE files together in a folder since my root folder is starting to get messy (bower, npm, tsd, etc.). I did not think going up a folder would be that complicated :/

Comment: symlink the files/directories you want inside your `appengine` dir. They'll be uploaded, but I'm not sure the app will still work, tho...

Comment: @DanCornilescu It worked!! For both the `serve` and `deploy`. You're a genius, hadn't thought of symlinks at all. Thanks so much!!! Awesome solution :D

Comment: Glad to hear. I made it an answer (and added some other symlink-related pointers that may be of interest)

Comment: Sure! I wish I could upvote your answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough rep points yet :( Thanks again for your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preserve your desired app structure with 3rd party code residing outside your GAE app code directory yet still be able to upload the 3rd party code together with your GAE app code by just symlinking the 3rd party code files/dirs inside the GAE app dir in the desired locations.

The GAE upload/deploy utilities know to replace the symlinks and upload the actual files/dirs the symlinks point to instead, in the respective locations.

Some other GAE-related scenarios in which the symlink technique can be applied:

- [Sharing entities between App Engine modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291075/sharing-entities-between-app-engine-modules/34291789#34291789)
- [How can I share files (HTML templates) between App Engine modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088104/how-can-i-share-files-html-templates-between-app-engine-modules/33091084#33091084)
- [Do I need to copy `skip_files` across multiple YAML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307128/do-i-need-to-copy-skip-files-across-multiple-yaml-files/33308640#33308640)
- [How do I access a vendored library from a module in Python Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973058/how-do-i-access-a-vendored-library-from-a-module-in-python-google-app-engine/34985211#34985211)
- [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo/34111170#34111170)