# Google App Engine - deploy with seed files from external directory?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been trying to deploy my go app on Google App Engine but I'm a bit stuck on how to make it include my seed-data files from a relative directory.
Project structure is:

```
- project
 |- cmd
 |    |- main.go
 |    |- app.yaml
 |
 |- seed-data
      |- foo.json
```

It works fine if I put `foo.json` next to `main.go` & `app.yaml` but how to I keep the structure and configure it to include the seed file from `../seed-data/foo.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory in which the `app.yaml` file exists is considered the top level directory for the respective GAE app service. Only what is below this top level service directory will be deployed to GAE.

In your case the `seed-data` directory is above the service's top level dir, so it won't be considered part of the service code at deployment. You need to address that.

If you're running in the standard environment it *should* be possible to use a properly located symlink to make the `seed-data` directory appear inside the service dir. See [How to upload a Google App Engine (Go) project in a different folder than the app.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230998/how-to-upload-a-google-app-engine-go-project-in-a-different-folder-than-the-ap/35261641#35261641)